# boolean modifier doesn't work when it should

Tags: modifiers

I want to cut holes in my object using another object to create windows, but when I apply boolean modifier which should work it doesn't. I get these weird lines all over my object and nothing happens(at least not what should happen)
see picture and blend file below:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you wanna do this:

[image]

1. delete your boolean modifier on cube.001
2. add boolean modifier to cube -> choose cube.001 as object
3. choose fast
4. hide cube.001 in viewport

to cut out all:

put all in one collection and use this:

[image]

Comment: thanks that worked

Comment: i updated my answer. Please click on the checkmark left of my answer, if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: On top of the issue Chris has pointed out, you should be aware that the top part of your windows have bad topology, as you can see: https://i.imgur.com/tXgW832.png It's not manifold (watertight). That's why the Exact mode is acting up. Fast mode will ignore such things to a degree, but you could end up having to deal with it sooner or later.